# Auto post in 2 domains

Tags: xml, wordpress, plugins, cron, feed

I need a help how to proceed my project, I have 2 domains www.english.com and www.spanish.com, both are blogging websites
What I'm trying to do here is, when I publish a post in domain www.english.com, I want the post to be published on domain www.spanish.com automatically.

What I'm thinking of doing here is: 
on publishing post on www.english.com, I create its xml with all it's meta values in that xml, and will run a cron job for publishing those posts on another www.spanish.com domain.

Is this the right way, can somebody please tell me a better way or any plugin for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This plugin might be useful for your case. [Push-Syndication](http://wordpress.org/plugins/push-syndication/)

For use case example, check [this](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-publish-to-multiple-wordpress-sites-from-a-single-install/) site.

Comment: There is one more thing that I forgot to add on is that, to new domain the post should be in another language(spanish), and I don't think if this plugin do that.

Comment: will you be using automated translation services? or two different posts in two languages?